# How can a control in a XAML in a WPF application use its own properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have following excerpt of a XAML in a C# WPF application and it is working fine:

```
<usercontrols:Own_Object Panel.ZIndex="5" Height="100" Width="77.5"
    Own_ObjectClickedCommand="{Binding ControlClickedCommand}"
    Level="1"
    Own_ObjectDto="{Binding Own_Objects, ConverterParameter=..., Converter={...}}"
```

Now I would like to set the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties, based on some properties of the `Own_ObjectDto` object. I tried as follows:

```
<usercontrols:Own_Object Panel.ZIndex="5" Height="100" Width="77.5"
    Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Own_ObjectDto.PosX, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
    Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Own_ObjectDto.PosY, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
    Own_ObjectClickedCommand="{Binding ControlClickedCommand}"
    Level="1"
    Own_ObjectDto="{Binding Own_Objects, ConverterParameter=..., Converter={...}}"
```

This is not working as `Own_ObjectDto` is not part of the viewmodel.

I don't want to include `Own_ObjectDto` into the viewmodel. I just want to use `Own_ObjectDto` as a source of some information.
Apparently I can't do that, using the `{Binding ...}` command.

How can I do this?

I also tried this, but it did not work either:

```
Canvas.Left="ShuttleDto.PosX"
```

Comment: `{Binding Own_ObjectsDto.PosX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`